# JS/Chrome Extension: how to check for logged in user

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, cookies

I've built a Chrome extension and now id' like to integrate it with my current website built in PHP where users have their own account and can save stuff (think something like pinterest)...

Is it possible to drop a cookie from PHP when they login to my website and read it from the Chrome/Js app? I just need to save the unique ID of the user, but I'm not sure if I can read my cookie from a different website...

What's the correct approach?

Answer (score -3):

Do it like this:

```
...
echo 'var id = ' + $id + ';';
...
```

And use the `id` variable in JS freely :)